# adding users programmatically in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using a combination of WSO2 Identity Server as key server and API Manager for API authorisation against roles.
My requirement is to provide Business users a UI where they can add a user, role and that should reflect in the WSO2. I am using the default user store.
How can I programmatically do this? Is there a REST service which I can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use identity server's [SCIM REST APIs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/SCIM+APIs) to add users and roles.

Before using this API, you have to enable SCIM in your userstore configurations in `user-mgt.xml`.

```
<Property name="SCIMEnabled">true</Property>
```

Comment: Thanks..Let me try this

Comment: Can  any of these API's support programmatic adding of a role to a scope?
If business users creates a new role ; can they map it to an existing scope programatically?

Comment: No, as per current the implementatoin scopes are immutable. Once they are created you can't modify them. They only can be deleted.

Comment: Is the Group in the SCIM documentation same as Roles?

Comment: Yes it's the same

Answer (score 5):

You can do user management functionalities programmatically using the [User Management APIs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/User+Management+with+APIs) exposed as SOAP services. These APIs allow you to manage user, user roles and claims etc.

If you cannot use the SOAP services you can use the [SCIM API](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/SCIM+APIs) which is a REST endpoint to do operations such as create, delete users. However, this has limited capabilities when compared to the User Management SOAP APIs.

Comment: Thanks..Let me try this